# Heroku doesnt serve bundled React JS application in Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I have the following gradle build configuration

```
node {
    version = '10.14.2'
    npmVersion = '6.5.0'
    download = true
    workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/node")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/webapp/chronos-ui")
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'chronos'
    version = '0.1.0'
    from("${project.projectDir}/src/main/webapp/chronos-ui/build") {
        into "${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources/static"
    }
}

task installFeDependencie(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install']
}

task buildFe(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run-script', 'build']
}

buildFe.dependsOn(installFeDependencie)
build.dependsOn(buildFe)
```

Basically it does the following:

1. Builds ReactJS application
2. Copies the build ReactJS application into jar file

When I locally execute`gradlew build` and then `java -jar jar_name.jar`

I am able to see the built React JS application  at the `localhost:8080`

However, when I deploy my app to the heroku, the access to the root URI provides me 404 error.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?